# Cordova, IOS 10 and the js appendChild method

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I've developped an hybrid application with the cordova framework.

-App is in production for android and ios users.

Since iphone users update their os to ios 10, the application doesn't work anymore.

Here is the link to the technical issue :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11882

Has someone the same issue ?

Comment: Do you have any error in console when you execute the code in console ? Also, if you want help on stackoverflow, please post the code here and not on external website.

Comment: No i don't have any errors or traces in console ! It's strange.
I've updated the ios-deploy 1.9.0 and have reinstalled all plugins

Comment: The solution seems to be here 
https://webkit.org/blog/6830/a-refined-content-security-policy/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response on the cordova jira platform :

This is an iOS 10 / Safari 10 CSP 2.0 issue and not a Cordova issue.
I ran the dev tools, and hit the Refresh button and the problem was evident:
"Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy."

See: https://webkit.org/blog/6830/a-refined-content-security-policy/ for a backwards compatible way to handle this